# 65 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am at wits end with this. I am learning React by doing Free Code Camp projects and ran into this issue while building projects locally (rather than running them on codepen.io).

Upon `npm install`, I got the following error message:

```
audited 46157 packages in 10.749s
found 65 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

`npm audit fix` didn't fix it (found SO threads about this). Learned about peer dependencies and looked up the Path and the vulnerable package and the dependent package.

Here is one of the vulnerabilities ...

[image]

Visited the [URL](https://npmjs.com/advisories/786) which described the vulnerability.

OK ... long story short:

- I have installed a newer version of the dependent package
  (**micromatch** from the example above).
- I have updated the braces package to the latest one
- Tried `npm install` once I confirmed that I have the most recent
  version of both the packages but still getting the same number of
  vulnerabilities.

  C02N696MG3QD:fccdrummachine kalyan.chatterjee$ npm view micromatch version
      3.1.10
      C02N696MG3QD:fccdrummachine kalyan.chatterjee$ npm view braces version
      2.3.2

What else can I do to resolve this? Please advise.

Comment: That's because maybe you have old versions of some libs or some libs have other libs with old versions as dependencies. I must say that you don't need to worry about this. Worry about this when you are building your own app/product. If you are just following an example or tutorial don't bother about this!

Comment: Ok let's assume that this is a production level banking app... what I am looking for is what I can do to resolve these. I have spend one full day on this but have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: In that case you should audit and check what are the libs that have these dependencies. If you have everything updated you should not get these warning

Comment: I have run "npm update" (inside the project folder) a few times. Still getting these warnings upon "npm audit". I will ignore these for now as these nuances impede learning.

Comment: You are updating YOUR OWN dependencies, but your dependencies may depend on other libs that are deprecated

Comment: I gave a very specific example. All packages here are active and being used. So my question is: even after I updated the dependent package and the package with the vulnerability... why do I continue to get exact same number of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Like I told you before, even the package being updated, it does not mean that the package uses the latest version for a specific lib... Try to remove `package-lock.json`, remove `node_modules` and then run `npm i` again

Comment: Didn't solve :(

Comment: Well, like I said before, some libs are using old versions of other libs. I don't think you will be able to fix this

Comment: Ok thanks. Will leave it to rest. Wasted enough time already.

Comment: copy you current project somewhere and try to run `npm audit fix --force` This will update package dependencies with `breaking change` option. In my case this is not break my app but fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue.